# Creating a C++ class or "entity" (or something equivalent) from Lua

Tags: c++, class, scripting, lua, game-engine

I'm using Lua for scripting in my C++ game. I want people to be able to create their own 'entities' like in Garry's Mod. The way it works is you create a new lua file, and you give the entity a name, description, baseclass/superclass to inherit (e.g. enemy) and you give it methods like new, update, draw etc. and you can use it like any other game entity.

So I want something like that, how could I do it? And I'm currently using LuaWrapper by alexames for registering my C++ classes to Lua.

I know it's possible, or else Garry's Mod wouldn't be able to do it...

Example:

```
-- my_enemy.lua
ENTITY.Name = "My Entity"
ENTITY.Type = TYPE_ENEMY

function ENTITY:new(x, y)
    -- do stuff
end

function ENTITY:update()
    -- do more stuff
end

function ENTITY:draw()
    -- do even more stuff
end
```

and create it by, for example: `game.newEntity(my_enemy, 0, 0)` in Lua.

(using ENTITY as the entity instead of my_enemy is just replicating how GMod does it.)

I'm not trying to make unique entities all with their own methods, I'm trying to make exactly what C++ classes are, but create them from Lua basically.

Comment: @Youka No, I'm not trying to show a C++ class to Lua. I'm trying to create an actual entity, from Lua, to C++, not the other way around.

Comment: Why not simply keep your entities in a container and use lua_pcall() when applicable? (i.e.: On draw phase, update phase, etc). Methods in lua are just regular functions, after all. Can you edit with a code sample of what are you trying to achieve?
Beware that I'm not familiar with LuaWrapper or Garry's Mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is a long answer but it's a pretty involved engine design question which is inherently pretty open-ended. I tried to give enough detail to help you out, assuming an intermediate level of knowledge with lua C api.

So, just as a disclaimer, there are lots of lua wrapper things out there and my preference is not to use any of them and instead just do everything directly using the lua C api, it's really not that bad... In what follows I'm going to describe how I would do it that way. In your case some parts of it might be better done with your lua wrapper somehow for more consistency with the rest of your engine but you're just going to have to figure that out yourself.

As I see it there's two things that fundamentally you need to be able to do. One is that C++ needs to be able to represent the "lua entity definition" (the 'class'), and the other is that C++ needs to be able to keep track of the instances of these classes so that it can call their draw and update methods as appropriate.

The first part is not too hard. What I would do first is, set it up so that there is a special table, stored in the lua registry, that stores all the different lua defined "classes" by name. So in the above example, when the engine decides that it needs to load "my_enemy" type, it will

(1) Push a table onto the stack (lua_newtable(L))

(2) Make a copy (reference) to it also on the stack (lua_pushvalue(L, -1))

(3) Set it to the global value "ENTITY" (lua_setglobal(L, "ENTITY"))
    This consumes the stack copy that was made, but leaves the original on the stack.

(4) Get the user defined classes table from the registry. (Using lua_gettable with the LUA_REGISTRYINDEX)

(5) Store the original, with the same string value, as a field of this table also. Now the global table and the special registry table both hold a copy of this table.

(6) Load the user defined script file as a chunk (lua_loadstring, lua_loadfile)

(7) Run it using lua_pcall (and configure an appropriate error handler function like debug.backtrace if you want to help your users) You're going to pass it no arguments, and it's going to return no arguments so the stack is empty after this.

(8) Clear the global variable "ENTITY" (by assigning nil to it)

I'm not familiar exactly with how Garry's mod works but you also need to provide the user a way to instantiate this class. So maybe you make a factory method for it available to the user somehow, or make another copy of the Entity table somewhere in the global space for them.

Now, there's something that you have to decide which is, when the user instantiates an entity, where does the entity object fundamentally live? Is it fundamentally a pure lua object, a table which C++ just knows about? Or is it fundamentally a C++ object, which lua represents as a "userdata", but really it has a C++ style lifetime. You could do this either way but I'm going to assume that you do the former, since it seems to fit a little better with the code example you posted.

In this case, the standard way that you would help C++ to keep track of pure lua tables is to use "luaL_Ref" and "luaL_Unref". The idea is that, you should have a second special table in the registry, in addition to the "user defined entity types" table, which represents "references to user defined entity instances". Basically, in the factory method that you provide to the user to instantiate their entities, you should make it call a C function that you write, which will

(1) get the special "entity instances" table from the registry (push it onto the stack)

(2) push onto the stack a copy of the table that is going to represent the entity instance that we give to the user's code (this can go before or after other code runs that initializes this table, it doesn't matter)

(3) Call luaL_Ref -- this stores the reference inside the entity instances table, at some particular integer index, and returns to C a long long corresponding to that index.

(4) In your C++ engine, you have some graphics loop that draws all the entities. You are going to also throw into the mix, a class or struct, maybe called "lua_userdefined_entity" which will contain that long long, and possibly also a pointer to the lua_State * if you have multiple lua_State's going on in your program? And this guy should have C++ methods "draw", "update", which conform to the signatures of your other c++ engine elements, but to implement those methods, what it will do is, go to the lua state, go to the registry and get the instances table, use that long long to look up the reference to the correct table. Then it's going to invoke the "update" or "draw" method as appropriate. Depending how you design it this might work a few ways -- maybe you will make it so that the table that was "Entity" really becomes the metatable of the instance, and then all you do is ask lua to grab the "update" method from this table, push arguments onto the stack and use pcall. Or, maybe it won't "technically" be the metatable from lua's point of view, and you'll just simulate that part of it yourself -- in this case you would store in your struct the name of the entity type, in addition to the long long, and you have to fetch both tables from the registry to make the function call happen. (The reason you might want to do it that way is to prevent the user from tampering with the metatable or something like that)

(5) In the destructor of the struct "lua_entity_instance", make it go to the lua State, get the instances table from the registry, and call luaL_Unref to release the reference to the users table. This allows lua to free memory when the object goes away and C++ no longer needs to be able to find it.

If you don't know about the lua registry / luaL_Ref etc., you should definitely read about those things, they are very useful and provide an alternative to making everything a userdata. IMO this is sometimes alot cleaner.

If you decide to do it all as userdata instead then basically you'll just implement all the plumbing of it in C++, and expose a thin interface to lua.

But note that if you decide to do it all as userdata, then most likely you will still end up storing the user-defined functions like update and draw inside the registry, and use the lua_Ref, Unref trick to keep track of those thing instead. Since you cannot return a lua function to the C++ code. (You could store it's source code instead I guess but then you will have to recompile it all the time and it will go a lot slower, don't do that. Also that will be broken if the user-defined function is actually a closure, because when you discard the function and recompile it it will lose track of its upvalues.)

Comment: Just a note, luaL_Ref will return a "LUA_INTEGER" in general, it's only a long long if you are using a typical configuration to build lua.